# @PropertySource not loading or erroring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using a `@Configuration` class, loading a property file using `@PropertySource`... something along the lines of :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:database.properties"})
```

This seems to be working just fine in a standalone java application.  However, if I then attempt to use the code in a `jetty` web app, it seems to be failing to load the properties.  While class path problems wouldn't surprise me in the least, what is surprising is that I'm not getting the FileNotFound exception.  So.. it's not loading the properties AND not complaining about it.

My `applicationContext.xml` contains the line:

```
<bean class="com.xxx.configuration.MyConfiguration"/>
```

My java application uses the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and calls `register()` with `MyConfiguration.class`.

Is the problem that the PropertySources requires an annotation scanner that's not initialized with my web app?  I have

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.configuration" />
```

also.. still didn't work.  I'd love to get this working, but at least getting the FileNotFound error would be a start!

I should note that I might be shooting myself in the foot.  One of the things I'm configuring is the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`... namely, a `PropertySource` that is remote and I need the remote host/port.  It might be that the `PropertySources` annotation requires an allocated `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to be working?  Chicken and egg?

Comment: try with this one

`@Configuration
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:/database.properties")})`

Comment: where is your file stored (in project/ in WAR)?

Comment: @ankur-singha, I had tried that, still no effect.

Comment: @sodik, I think I've put it pretty much everywhere, but the fact that the PropertySource annotation isn't throwing a FileNotFoundException makes me think it's not even trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I resolved my error.  It's related to [my question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271537/remote-propertysource/25272466#25272466).  It's related to the fact that I was attempting to create a PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer that itself needed values from a PropertySource.  I was unaware that the annotation would use that bean.  It was a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: sadly, it is not working for me, why would spring do that? why?