# Remote PropertySource

Tags: spring

Has anyone had any luck constructing a PropertySource that uses a remote source (for example a database) from which to retrieve property values.  The idea would be to construct a PropertySource (needs some connection information such as host/port) and plug that into a PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer.

The problem seems to be a chicken and egg problem.  How can I get the connection information down to the PropertySource?  I could first instantiate the PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer with configuration to load a property file with the remote host and port properties and then later instantiate the PropertySource and inject that back into the configurer.  However, I can't seem to figure a way to ensure that the very first bean to be instantiated (and quickly injected into the configurer) is my property source.  I need to have this because, of course, all my other beans depend on the remote properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/index.html)  supports loading properties from a variety of sources (including JDBC Datasources) into a `org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration` object via a `org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationBuilder`.

Using the `org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfiguratorConverter`, you can convert the Configuration object into a `java.util.Properties` object which can be passed to the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

As to the chicken and egg question of how to configure the ConfigurationBuilder, I recommend using the `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` to query for system properties, command-line properties or JNDI properties.

In this exampe:

```
@Configuration
public class RemotePropertyConfig {

   @Bean
   public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer(Environment environment)
    throws Exception {
    final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer props = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    final ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder(environment.getProperty("configuration.definition.file"));
    props.setProperties(ConfigurationConverter.getProperties(configurationBuilder.getConfiguration()));
    return props;
}
```

You will need to specify the environment property `configuration.definition.file` which points to a file needed to configure Commons Configuration:

Comment: This turned out to be a solve for me... I was actually just typing up a similar solution when you posted this.  I'll post my solution below.  Thanks @Ricardo Veguilla

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Recardo's answer above, I used Spring's PropertiesLoaderUtils instead of Apache's, but it amounts to the same thing.  It's not exactly ideal.. hard coded dependency injection, but hey, it works!

```
/**
 * This method must remain static as it's part of spring's initialization effort.
 * @return
 **/
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

  String dbHost = null;
  Integer dbPort = null;

  // check system / environment properties first
  Environment environment = new StandardEnvironment();
  if (environment.containsProperty(DB_HOST_KEY)) {
    dbHost = environment.getProperty(DB_HOST_KEY);
  }
  if (environment.containsProperty(DB_PORT_KEY)) {
    dbPort = Integer.valueOf(environment.getProperty(DB_PORT_KEY));
  }

  if (dbHost == null || dbPort == null) {
    // ok one or (probably) both properties null, let's go find the database.properties file
    Properties dbProperties;
    try {
      dbProperties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(new EncodedResource(new ClassPathResource("database.properties"), "UTF-8"));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Could not load database.properties.  Please confirm the file is in the classpath");
    }

    if (dbHost == null) {
      dbHost = dbProperties.getProperty(DB_HOST_KEY);
    }
    if (dbPort == null) {
      dbPort = Integer.valueOf(dbProperties.getProperty(DB_PORT_KEY));
    }
  }

  PropertySourceService propertySourceService = new DBPropertySourceService(dbHost, dbPort);
  PropertySource<PropertySourceService> propertySource = new DBPropertySource(propertySourceService);
  MutablePropertySources propertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
  propertySources.addFirst(propertySource);
  configurer.setPropertySources(propertySources);

  return configurer;
}
```

per request, here is the source of the remote property source.  It depends on a 'service' class that might do.. well.. anything.. remote access of a property over a socket, talk to a database, whatever.

```
/**
 * Property source for use with spring's PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer where the source is a service
 * that connects to remote server for property values.
 **/
public class RemotePropertySource extends PropertySource<PropertySourceService> {

  private final Environment environment;
  /**
   * Constructor...
   * @param name
   * @param source
   **/
  public RemotePropertySource(PropertySourceService source) {
    super("RemotePropertySource", source);
    environment = new StandardEnvironment();
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource#getProperty(java.lang.String)
   */
  @Override
  public Object getProperty(String name) {

    // check system / environment properties first
    String value;
    if (environment.containsProperty(name)) {
      value = environment.getProperty(name);
    }
    else {
      value = source.getProperty(name);
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your implementation of the actual PropertySource?

Comment: PropertySource is just a spring framework class: org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource