# Is it necessary to use Commons Configuration to use @PropertySource in Spring 5.x?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am unable to load property file in resources directory,

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/test.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class ArgConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${store.name}")
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

test.properties contains -->
store.name=nike

[Property Source from Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

Followed the same from the documentation still unable to load the properties file.

Comment: What makes you think this is even remotely dependend on Commons Configuration? Remove the `ignoreResourceNotFound` and it will probably throw an exception.. If not you are doing weird things in this and I wonder how you are trying to achieve this.

Comment: Can you show the directory structure of your project?

Comment: @M. Denim, I was referring to the post [reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271537/remote-propertysource/25272466#25272466). Property file is under /com/sk/config/store.properties. `@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/sk/config/store.properties")
public class StoreConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public Store testBean() {
        Store store = new Store();
        store.setName(env.getProperty("store.name"));
        return store;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for wasting precious time.

I found the answer, it is just to place the property file under resource directory(which I did even before but not sure why it thrown error).

Here is the entire code,
Project structure:
[image]

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SampleRestController {

    @Autowired
    private Store storeDetails;

    @GetMapping("/names")
    public List<String> getNames(){
        String storeName = storeDetails.getName();
        System.out.println("Store Name = " + storeName);
        return storeName!=null ? Arrays.asList(storeName) : Arrays.asList("store1","store2","store3");
    }
}

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/store.properties")
public class StoreConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public Store storeDetails() {
        Store store = new Store();
        store.setName(env.getProperty("store.name"));
        return store;
    }
}

@Component
public class Store {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory for you to use it as `test.properties`? if so, use the `@PropertySource` annotation. Otherwise, use it like `application-test.properties` and set the profile as `test` using `@ActiveProfiles("test")`

Another way is, place your application.properties under `src/test/resources` if you want to override the value.

Refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests-override-properties for more information

Comment: I want to use `@PropertySource` and see its purpose of loading specific properties file (test is just a sample name)for specific configuration `@Configuration`. It is quite a feature worth using it Ian any situation that's why wanted to explore its feature.